# Blank Window Opening when running google Spreadsheet script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script Object is to open a Html window in spreadsheet and select any button, then after a script should run Once a particular button is clicked.

My script does everything except one additional step, It opens a blank window every time I make a selection.

Here is my HTML Code :-

```
<script> 

window.addEventListener('load', displayButtons());

function displayButtons(){
document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML+='<button style="margin-right:4px;" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).FULLFEED();">FULL FEED</button>';
document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML+='<button style="margin-right:4px;" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).AIU();">Automatic Item Update</button>'; 
document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML+='<button style="margin-right:4px;" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).TOPSKU();">TOP SKU</button>';
document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML+='<button style="margin-right:4px;" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).LIA();">LIA</button>'; 
document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML+='<button style="margin-right:4px;" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).QA();">Quality Analysis</button>';
}

</script>
```

and here is my apps script :-

```
function Popup() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index5');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .showModalDialog(html, 'Select Procedure');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
html.setHeight(600).setWidth(288);
ss.show(html);
}


function FULLFEED()
{ Zoom(); }

function AIU()
{ AIURUN(); }

function TOPSKU()
{ TOPSKURUN(); }


function LIA()
{ LIARUN(); }

function QA()
{ QARUN();  }
```

Can you please let me know why a strange blank browser window is popping up if I make any selection, FYI my functions are perfectly running fine.

Comment: What should be done here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zVcKk0YziQYBNmTumNDC0_aT2bVxIl9plLXpAYO9e7w/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet you would like to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When these functions (`Zoom(), AIURUN(), TOPSKURUN(), QARUN()`) in GAS side work fine, no errors occur. And the window is not left. In your question, you say that these work fine.

So I saw your script editor. It was found that the reason is `<base target="_top">`. `_top` means that the frame display is canceled and the link destination page is displayed in the entire window. So please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
<base target="_top">
```

#### To :

```
<base target="_self">
```

OR

```
<base href="" target="_top">
```

#### Reference :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! I really appreciate your effort it works now.

Comment: @Sharad Gurung Thank you, too.